# Flicker with ngMessages and ngShow

Tags: html, angularjs, flicker, ng-show, ng-messages

On a form with `required`-validation and `ng-messages` I use `ng-show` to hide the directive on startup and only show error messages after the input got `ng-dirty`.

To still keep the element filling it's space in the layout I have following css rule to overwrite the default `ng-hide` behaviour:

```
ng-messages.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate), [ng-messages].ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate)
{
    display: block !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

When I now enter text in the input field the error message is shortly visible before it is then hidden again (due to the required field being filled). It somehow feels like `ng-dirty` is resolved before the form validation is done, resulting in this behaviour.

See **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aides/vjt2ns33/3/)**

or check out the

**Code:**

```js
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMessages', 'ngAnimate']);
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', UserCtrl]);

function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showField = true;
    $scope.reset = function() {
        var master = { name: '' };
        $scope.temp = angular.copy(master);
        $scope.user_form.$setPristine();
    }  
}
```

```css
ng-messages.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate), [ng-messages].ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate)
{
   display: block !important;
   visibility: hidden;
}

ng-messages, [ng-messages]
{
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
}

input
{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <form name="user_form" novalidate>
            <input name="name" ng-model="temp.name" ng-show="showField" placeholder="Name" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <ng-messages ng-show="user_form.name.$dirty" for="user_form.name.$error">
              <ng-message when="required">
                Please enter your name
              </ng-message>
            </ng-messages>
            <button type="button" class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>     
        </form>
        <p>
            Pristine: {{user_form.$pristine}}
        </p>
        
        <pre>Errors: {{user_form.$error | json}}</pre>
              
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ng-messages ng-show="user_form.name.$dirty && !user_form.name.$valid" for="user_form.name.$error">
```

Comment: Oha, that did work! I did try similar things without success. Could you explain why this flicker occurs and how this statement helps preventing it?